# Angular:bash: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, angular

for some reason, ng-v ,ng-version,ng v doesn't work for me;does anyone can help?
ng v
-bash: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng: No such file or directory

i already installed angular/cli;node js and npm; everything looks fine;

├── @angular/cli@9.1.0
├── jsonfile@6.0.1
└── npm-check-updates@4.1.1

i install and remove angular multiple times already;nothing change;

also,I try to fix it with the code below, it shows the file exists;somehow doesn't work for ng-v
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.16.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng /usr/local/bin/ng
ln: /usr/local/bin/ng: File exists

Answer (score 0):

Install Angular -g globally

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Angular location in your machine

```
npm list -g @angular/cli
```

Copy the Angular Path :

`Example:`

/home/<YOUR-PC-NAME/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Press `i` : To Insert

Paste your PATH with export keyword

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/<YOUR-PC-NAME>/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/lib/node_modules/@ang lar/cli/bin/ng
```

Save and Exit with : `Esc` > `:wq!` > `Press Enter`

Source the file with

```
 source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers to multiple questions.

Comment: Sorry for that!